# Adding tags to open-source ads

Tags: feature-request, tags, open-source-advertising

The open-source ads are a wonderful idea and I want to thank you for that great possibility!

Nontheless, I suggest an optimization: Couldn't we add preferred tags to these ads (e.g. python, php etc.) so that they get even more effective?
I guess there are probably not enough ads to only base it on these tags, but they could be seen as a matter of preference.

As far as I understand, that is in your interest, too. :)

Comment: StackExchange already has such information and can target ads anyway, if they wanted. But they seem to have a shortage of ads fitting their criteria already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287302/248268